Simple code example to implement tax on sell/buy transactions for a token on Uniswap DEX causing "Your swap is expected to fail.." error
I am trying to implement a sell/buy tax on transactions for my token when users trade on Uniswap DEX. My token's smart contract includes a tax deduction mechanism that functions correctly on EtherScan but encounters issues when traded on a DEX like PancakeSwap. Lets say a user want to sell 100 token to on a DEX but token smart contract deduct 5 tokens and transfer 95 tokens to DEX, DEX gives error back, the error is:
"Your swap is expected to fail. Try increasing your slippage tolerance. Note: fee-on-transfer and rebase tokens are incompatible with Uniswap V3."


Because DEX is expecting the full 100 tokens amount which was promised.
Any how I tried setting the slippage tolerance well above the tax amount, but the transactions still fail.
1. Could someone provide a basic code example or guidance on how to ensure the tax logic works without causing the transaction to fail on DEXs?
2. Is there a known compatibility issue with this kind of tax implementation on platforms like Uniswap V3?
3. Do I need to create my own DEX to properly implement and manage such a feature?
